# What are escape characters on Python?

Tags: python

My HW task says-
*Write a program that says:
    This is (your name)'s first program
Put your name in where the brackets are represented. Make sure that you use correct punctuation and an apostrophe is in the correct place.
HINT: You will need what is called an escape character in this code*

Iv tried googling escape characters on python but with no luck.
Can someone please explain what I need to do?

Comment: They mean you need `\'` inside your quote to print a single quote. They're also quite wrong, and it's possible you're being taught by someone who doesn't actually know Python. (You can can an unescaped single quote in your code, if the larger string is within double quotes. Or either kind of triple quotes.)

Comment: You must need to update your version of Goole: https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the escape characters to invoke special characters, in this case apostrophe.

But you don't need it.

If you run the program like this:

```
 print("This is Blank's first program")
```

or like this:

```
 print("This is Blank\'s first program")
```

Both will give the same output.

But if you did something like this:

```
print('This is Blank's first program')
```

Then an error will appear. That's where you need to apply escape characters.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That's the wrong answer, let me fix it.

Comment: The point is given the question you are asking the top one shouldn't work.  The necessity of escape characters is demonstrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
print('I love python's syntax')
```

will give you an error.

```
print('I love python\'s syntax')
```

will not.